# Getting Spotify play history through either the Web API or libspotify

Tags: javascript, c, facebook-graph-api, spotify, libspotify

Is there a way to get my Spotify play history using either their js or C APIs? I saw a couple of examples, but that was using their outdated API version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spotify play history is not available through any API.

Disclaimer: I'm a Spotify employee.

Comment: Do you plan on making it available in the future?

Comment: Highly unlikely in the short term, as in, it's not planned as far as I know. (I'm also a Spotify employee). There is however a twist. If you are interested in getting _your_ play history and _you_ have scrobbled all of your plays to last.fm, you could extract all of it using http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks

Comment: What about getting access through the Facebook Open Graph?

Comment: is this still unsupported ?

Comment: @MarianoLatorre et al. as mentioned by mrowa44 below, this is possible now!

Answer (score 11):

Support for this has been added recently: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-personalization-endpoints/get-recently-played/

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"
```

Comment: This endpoint only gives access to the "recently played" list. Is there a way to get the full playing history by dates?

Comment: Unfortunately, with this method you can only get the 50 last played tracks, not the entire history. I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it.

The [JavaScript Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) doesn't have a method for authentication.

The [libspotify C API](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/) will handle authentication, but I don't see anything about a user's history. I could be missing it, as I'm not a C expert.

Answer (score 1):

Users can connect Spotify to Last.fm, which does store and give access to a user's play history.